# PHP Replace keyword from key-value in multidimension array using string_replace

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, dynamic-arrays

I have a multidimensional array like this

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Foo
            [1] => Bar
            [2] => I like foobar
            [3] => 09/09/2014
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Foo2
            [1] => Bar2
            [2] => Very much
            [3] => 10/09/2014
        )
)
```

keys array which looks like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => From
        [1] => To
        [2] => Text
        [3] => Schedule Date
    )
```

and a message is a string variable

```
$message = "Hi {To} message is from {From} come get {Text}.
```

My question is how do I replace the keywords between `{$key}` for all the array values at the same time to produce a new `$messages` array containing the messages with keywords replaced?

This has to be done dynamically and not hard coded because different values will be used every time.

Comment: Is there any relations between arrays? Is 0th element from first array will always be `{from}`?

Comment: I array_slice() the first array so that I get 2 arrays one for keywords and another for the values I want to replace. Essentialy the keywords array is array[0]. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some commented code for you. This should work for you as long as the number of keys matches the number of elements in your input array. This also assumes your placeholders match your key names.

```
//input data    
$inputs = array();

$inputs[0][] = 'Foo';
$inputs[0][] = 'Bar';
$inputs[0][] = 'I like foobar';
$inputs[0][] = '09/09/2014';

$inputs[1][] = 'Foo2';
$inputs[1][] = 'Bar2';
$inputs[1][] = 'Very much';
$inputs[1][] = '10/09/2014';

//keys for the input data
$keys = array('From', 'To', 'Text', 'Schedule Date');

//message template
$message = "Hi {To} message is from {From} come get {Text}.";

$messages = array();

//Loop through the input data
foreach($inputs as $input) {
   $input = array_combine($keys, $input); //give input array our custom keys

   $userMessage = $message; //create a copy of the message template

   //Loop through the values replacing `{$key}` with $value
   foreach($input as $key=>$value) { 
       $userMessage = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $userMessage);
   }

   //Do something with the message
   $messages[] = $userMessage;

}

print_r($messages);

//Outputs:
//Array
//(
//    [0] => Hi Bar message is from Foo come get I like foobar.
//    [1] => Hi Bar2 message is from Foo2 come get Very much.
//)
```

Online demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab578560f6e7f58969928e44404602b030bb01db).

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net](http://php.net//manual/es/function.str-replace.php): `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

So assuming you have:

```
Array1 (original): $arr1
Array2 (replace): $arr2
```

You could do:

```
foreach($arr2 as $key => $value) 
{
    $newMessage = str_replace ($arr1[$key], $value, $message, 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to have the first array in this format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        ['From'] => 'Foo',
        ['To'] => 'Bar',
        ['Text'] => 'Message text',
        ['Schedule_Date'] => '01/01/01',
    ),
    ...
)
```

Then you can do this in a loop:

```
$message = "Hi {To} message is from {From} come get {Text}.";
foreach ($array as $toSend) {
    $messageReplaced = $message;
    foreach ($toSend as $key => $value) {
        $messageReplaced = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $value, $messageReplaced);
    }
    $this->mail->send($messageReplaced, $toSend['Schedule_Date']); // just an example
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is similar to @cOle2. It helped alot

Comment: @zinyando It is a good manor here at SO to accept the answer you have used (and that helped you) by clicking on the *tick* icon to the left of the answer. It is also good manor to *upvote* other good answers or to *downvote* the answers that are completely bad (after you have received at least 250 exp) - by clicking on the up/down arrow icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your title array is `$titles`, if the placeholders in your template were the same as the titles (e.g. `{From}` instead of `From`) then you could trivially do the replacement with

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    $result = str_replace($titles, $row, $template);
    // now do something with $result
}
```

Since this is so convenient and the placeholders are *almost* the same as the titles, it's very tempting to convert the titles into placeholders first and then do the above:

```
$titles = ['From', 'To', 'Text'];
$placeholders = array_map(function($t) { return '{'.$t.'}'; }, $titles);
foreach($data as $row) {
    $result = str_replace($placeholders, $row, $template);
    // now do something with $result
}
```